# Collections and sub-collections in Backbone (and their associated views)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm creating my very first app with Backbone.
Basically, I have a two-level deep  unordered list.

```
<ul class="cabinet">
  <li class="drawer"> 
    <a>Drawer 1</a>
    <ul class="boxes">
      <li> Box 1 </li>
      <li> Box 2 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="drawer"> 
    <a>Drawer 2</a>
    <ul class="boxes">
      <li> Box 3 </li>
      <li> Box 4 </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

In Backbone, I created two collections ("Drawers" and "Boxes"), with their associated Views.
My problem is that I don't know how should I handle the second level list items.

At this moment, I have a single Backbone Collection for boxes and each time I add new Box to
the collection, it will be render under each drawer. I should somehow separate the group of boxes based on the parent drawer but I don't know how can I do this in the "Backbone way".

In other words, let's say I need to add Box 3 and Box 4 elements to Drawer 2.
How can I render this two "boxes" under "Drawer 2". Should I have a separate collection for each drawer's group of boxes? If so, how can I dynamically create a collection with this purpose in Backbone? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from your description, it looks like Drawer should be a model, not a collection. You could have a collection called Drawers, which would contain instances of Drawer.

Second, There are two main ways to do this. Which method you choose is really up to your judgment as to which more accurately represents the relationship between boxes and drawers and which will allow you to handle your data efficiently.

1. If groups of boxes are primarily related to their parent drawer, then, when you initialize each drawer and give it a Boxes collection:

   ```
   var drawer_set = [];

   var args = {
     label: 'Drawer 1',
     boxes: new Boxes()
   };

   drawer_set.push(new Drawer(args));

   var drawers = new Drawers(drawer_set);
   ```
2. If you want to be able to quickly run processes on all of your boxes, you would want two collections: one of boxes and one of drawers, where each box has an attribute saying which drawer it's in.

   ```
   var args = { drawer: 1 };
   var box = new Box(args);
   var boxes = new Boxes(boxes);
   ```

Then, you can select your drawers by box via:

```
var boxes_in_drawer_1 = boxes.where({drawer: 1});
```

Comment: yes, it's Drawers (a collection). I think the first method it's the one I should use in my case. Thank you a lot for your suggestions!